# CreateUser function not running at all

Tags: angularjs, function, angularfire

I'm trying to achieve a user creation in Firebase but the function that would do it just gets skipped completely for some reason. I've done this a thousand times before but now I can't figure out why this function isn't being run at all, it's driving me insane so hopefully someone can point out what I've done wrong here.

I've got a button that is connected to a form, and when you click this button it will call a `validate` function:

```
<button ng-click="validate()">Submit</button>

$scope.validate = function() {
    $scope.error = validation.validateSignup($scope.user);
    $scope.error ? false : $scope.error = dbEntry.createNewUser($scope.user);
}
```

Which will call a factory method and if no errors are returned, it will call the `createNewUser` method of the `dbEntry` factory.

A factory which points to either a reference, synced reference or an authentication object. The latter is what I'm using to create a new user. See documentation for this [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-createusercredentials).

```
forumApp.factory('fbRef', ['$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth) {

    return {
        getReference: function(path) {
            return path ? new Firebase('https://blabla.firebaseio.com/' + path) : new Firebase('https://forum-app.firebaseio.com/');  
        },
        getSyncedReference: function(path) {
            return $firebase(new Firebase('https://blabla.firebaseio.com/' + path));
        },
        getAuthObj: function() {
            return $firebaseAuth(new Firebase('https://blabla.firebaseio.com/'));
        }
    };
}]);
```

Example `user` object that gets passed to `createNewUser` method:

```
$scope.user = {
    firstname: 'Chris',
    lastname: 'Ferguson',
    age: '21',
    country: 'Sweden',
    displayName: 'BadBoy13',
    email: 'badboy13@gmail.com',
    password: 'mothercow',
    confirmedPassword: 'mothercow',
    isTermsAccepted: true
}
```

The factory which contains the `createNewUser` method that will register a new account in the Firebase database.

**UPDATED FACTORY - It now runs but I keep getting the default "Connection error- try again later" in the switch statement when I try to insert anything into the database:**

```
forumApp.factory('dbEntry', ['$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', 'fbRef', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
    return {
        /**
         * Create a new user account in Firebase
         *
         * @param Object $user
         *  User details
         *
         * @return String
         *  If error -> error message
         *  If successful -> success message
         */
        createNewUser: function(user) {

            return fbRef.getAuthObj().$createUser({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(userData) {
                console.log(userData);
                return 'Registration successful';
            }).catch(function(error) {

                switch (error.code) {

                    case 'EMAIL_TAKEN': 
                        return 'Email already registered';

                    default: 
                        return 'Connection error - try again later';
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Could someone point out what is wrong here?

Comment: `createNewUser` inside factory should have return as `return fbRef.getAuthObj().$createUser({});`

Comment: @pankajparkar Fixed one problem but the problem of the function itself not being run remains.

Comment: `$scope.error`  should be set using `.then` because `createNewUser` returns promise..try `dbEntry.createNewUser($scope.user).then(function(data){
$scope.error =  data ? true: false
});`

Comment: @pankajparkar The problem still remains that the function does not want to run.. I've updated the factory, take a look.

Comment: @pankajparkar Cancel that, it runs now, but it's not inserting into database for some reason..

Comment: `validation.validateSignup($scope.user)` is this ajax again?

Comment: @pankajparkar "validation" is a factory and "validateSignup" is the method. No AJAX there.

Comment: @pankajparkar It works now, added a console log and everything just suddenly worked.. (SIGH). If you add your comments as a full answer I will accept it because it did solve the problem. :)

Comment: sure I'll do that soon..does my 3rd comment was useful?

Comment: @pankajparkar The one about validation? No, that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: That's Cool..that means you only missed to return promise from factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createNewUser` method of `dbEntry` factory is returning a promise, but in your you didn't returned the promise. `fbRef.getAuthObj().$createUser({})` method should return from factory.

**CODE**

```
forumApp.factory('dbEntry', ['$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', 'fbRef', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
    return {
        createNewUser: function(user) {
            //returning promise that will return to method who is accessing it.
            return fbRef.getAuthObj().$createUser({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(userData) {
                console.log(userData);
                return 'Registration successful';
            }).catch(function(error) {

                switch (error.code) {

                    case 'EMAIL_TAKEN': 
                        return 'Email already registered';

                    default: 
                        return 'Connection error - try again later';
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.validate = function() {
    $scope.error = validation.validateSignup($scope.user);
    $scope.error ? false : $scope.error = dbEntry.createNewUser($scope.user);
}
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.